# Using "WHERE" with a variable that has multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, oracle10g, where-clause

I want to know how to select columns from a table where another column has several possible values. So, for example, this code will return Column X from table 1 and Column B from Table 2 if Column G has the value given by the input.

```
variable input varchar2(60);
exec :input := 'c';

Select Table1.x, Table2.b
  FROM Table1, 
       Table2
 WHERE Table1.g = :input
```

What if instead, I wanted to return Column X from `table1` and `ColumnB` from `Table2` if `ColumnG` had value "k" or "c" or "d" without doing

```
WHERE Table1.g = "k" or Table1.g = "c" or Table1.g = "d"
```

How do i define the input such that I get this effect?

I use: oracle 10g, PL/SQL

Comment: Does it have to be a bind variable?  A substitution variable might make this very easy.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your comment to @SuperMan answer

> Yes, is there any way to define a variable to be a placeholder for the
>   ('c', 'd', 'k')?

you want to parametrize `IN` clause.

Obviously you cannot pass the `:input` variable in the `IN` clause defined like this `exec :input := 'k,c,d'`. I mean, technically you can, but the query wont produce the desired output because it will search for the entire `'k,c,d'` string.

What you can do is, you can split the `'k,c,d'`(or any other) string by comma and use the result in the `IN` clause.

Here is an example:

```
-- variable of this type will contain letters produced by 
-- splitting 'k,c,d' string
create or replace type T_vars as table of varchar2(5)

-- This table function returns collection of individual letters
create or replace function GetLetters(p_input in varchar2)
return t_vars
is
  l_res T_Vars;
begin
  select cast(
              collect(
                       cast(res as varchar2(5))
                      ) as T_Vars
             )
    into l_res
    from ( select regexp_substr(p_input, '[^,]+', 1, level) as res
             from dual
          connect by level <= regexp_count(p_input, '[^,]+' )
          );

  return l_res;
end;
```

Here is how it works:

```
SQL> variable x varchar2(11);

SQL> exec :x := 'k,c,d';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select col
  2    from table1
  3   where col in (select column_value from table(getletters(:x)))
  4  ;
```

Result:

```
 COL
 ---
 k
 c
 d
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this?

```
Select Table1.x, Table2.b
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.g  in ('c', 'd', 'k')
```

Edit - reply on comment: [It is not straight forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause) or [take a look here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425).

Comment: Yes, is there any way to define a variable to be a placeholder for the ('c', 'd', 'k')? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pl/sql a FOR loop can be used to run the query for each value. 
Something like this:

```
FOR x in ('k','c','d')
loop
Select Table1.x, Table2.b into var1,var2
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.g = x
dbms_output.put_line(var1,var2);
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straight forward -

```
Select Table1.X, Table2.B FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.g IN ('c', 'd', 'k')
```

Basically it will give you a Cartesian product of all row from table 1 where Table1.g = c or d or k and all rows from Table2 since you don't have any another join condition.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
where table1.g in ("k","c","d")
```

Comment: It works, I just wonder if I can define a variable which will be a placeholder of the stuff in parenthesis. Thank you